# How to specify snowflake options in spark session?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to run a query from spark to Snowflake by running something like :-

sparkSession.sql("query");

So i wanted to understand where can i specify the below snowflake options while creating the sparksession itself.

```
val defaultOptions = Map(
     "sfURL" -> "",
     "sfAccount" > "",
      "sfUser" -> "",
      "sfPassword" -> "",
     "sfDatabase" -> "",
     "sfSchema" -> "public",
     "sfWarehouse" -> ""
)
```

Although i know that i can use these options with spark connector something like this below :-

```
  def snowflakedf(sql: String) = { 
             spark.read
             .format("net.snowflake.spark.snowflake")
             .options(defaultOptions)
             .option("query", sql")
             .load()
           }
```

but my problem is i have to specifically use spark sql only to run the query.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Rahul, have you had a chance to check out previous answers using the pyspark python module like:  https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/configuring-spark-to-use-snowflake-using-pyspark and https://community.snowflake.com/s/question/0D50Z000092i8ZM/how-to-extract-data-from-snowflake-to-spark-using-sql-and-pyspark ?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding USING and OPTIONS to the SQL statement. I've used this before to create a global table in HIVE from a Snowflake datasource:

```
user = "<username>"
password = "<password>"
​
sf_url="<ACCOUNT>.snowflakecomputing.com"
sf_database="<SF_DB>"
sf_schema="<SF_SCHEMA>"
sf_warehouse="<SF_WF>"
sf_table="<SF_TABLE>"

create_table_str = "CREATE TABLE {0} (ID decimal(38,0)) 
  USING net.snowflake.spark.snowflake 
  OPTIONS (`sfURL`='{1}',`sfUser`='{2}',`sfPassword`='{3}',`sfDatabase`='{4}',`sfSchema`='{5}',`sfWarehouse`='{6}',`dbtable` = '{7}')"
  .format(sf_table, sf_url, user, password, sf_database, sf_schema, sf_warehouse, sf_table )

spark.sql(create_table_str)
```